# Copying redux state to component state is good way to optimize react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I need to change app state I copy part of redux state to component state and work with local state like this

```
export class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: this.props.user,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.user.name}
          onChange={this.changeUserName}
        />
        <button onClick={this.saveUser}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  userNameChange = ({target}) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      user: {
        ...prevState.user,
        name: target.value,
      },
    }));
  }

  saveUser = () => {
    const {
      userActions,
    } = this.props;

    const {
      user,
    } = this.state;

    userActions.save(user);
  }
}

const mapStateToUserProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

const mapDispatchToUserProps = (dispatch) => ({
  userActions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch),
})

export const UserContainer = connect(mapStateToUserProps, mapDispatchToUserProps)(User);
```

This will prevent redux selectors from being called.
Is this good way to optimize app or should all changes be made only to reducers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are not much different, because finally you want to save/edit your data, so you need to send a `request` at the end.

It's more important to create an app with fewer requests and if you have big data you should try to filter your data as much as possible in `server-side`.

If you won't have/change some local variable you should use state, otherwise, you should use your `redux store`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I mean user name changing will dispatch many actions and user saving will dispatch one action.